# How to generate clean API Docs for my CakePHP project

Tags: cakephp, documentation, cakephp-2.1

What's the best and easiest way to generate clean and simple API Docs for my CakePHP Project?
All Methods are commented using PHPDoc Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the Api Generator project developed by the CakePHP team: https://github.com/cakephp/api_generator